# why is the third flux term in the conservative euler equation positive regardless of the direction of velocity?

Tags: finite-volume

The $\rho u^2 + p$ term corresponds to the flux of $x$-momentum through some surface. According to this equation it would give a positive momentum flux if $u$ was positive or negative. This does not make sense to me as if the velocity was reversed the momentum flux should be negative. Why is this term positive?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is derived from momentum balance, so there is nothing wrong with. But you can resolve the apparent paradox like this. Take a square control volume $C = [a,b] \times [c,d]$ and look at x-momentum balance
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_C \rho u dx dy = -\int_c^d (\rho u^2)(b,y) dy + \int_c^d (\rho u^2)(a,y) dy + \ldots
$$
The first term on the right is the convective flux of momentum across the right face of $C$.  In first term, if $u > 0$, fluid is going out of $C$ and you lose x-momentum. On the other hand, if $u < 0$, fluid is entering $C$ but you still lose x-momentum because the incoming fluid has negative x-momentum. So in either case, you lose x-momentum due to momentum convection across the right face. The situation is reversed for the left face, you always gain x-momentum due to convective flux across the left face.